# How do I apply for EU Blue Card after receiving job offer from Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit, blue-card

I have received a job offer from Germany and currently in the process of applying for visa. My employer has asked me to apply for visa to obtain a residence permit under act 18 (which is for employment). However, I am interested in applying for a EU Blue card. Do I have to mention it while applying for the work visa here in my home country or I apply for the Blue Card when I reach Germany? 
P.S. - I fulfil the minimum requirements for the Blue Card.
Thank You!

Comment: What is your nationality? The procedure differs based on citizenship/

Comment: Hi @Das - what happened to you? Did you get the regular work permit or the blue card? How long did it take?

Comment: Hi @FilipeMiranda, Since I fulfill the requirements for the Blue card I have applied for it. I haven't got the card yet but as long as you have all the necessary documents, you can apply for it.

Answer (score 4):

[EU Blue Card: Live & Work in Europe](http://www.eu-bluecard.com/) explains how and what to do [I**f You Have Found a Job in Germany**](http://www.eu-bluecard.com/eu-blue-card-germany/).

> If you have already found a job – either while in your home country or while in Germany, then the following are the documents you need when applying:
>
> - For unregulated professions  – a recognized university diploma,
> - In case of regulated profession – present the acquired certificate,
> - A work contract of at least one year in Germany,
> - Proof that your salary exceeds the average in Germany by 1.5 times or 1.2 times for professions in shortage,
> - A written declaration by your employer in Germany,
> - A valid travel document,
> - Proof of no threat to the public policy, security or health of the hosting state,
> - An application form, filled either by you or your German employer,
> - Two passport-size personal photos, not older than 6 months,
> - Proof of application fee payment,
> - [Health insurance proof](http://www.eu-bluecard.com/eu-blue-card-germany/#Health-Insurance-Germany)
>
> You should apply by post at the authorized [Federal Office for Migration or Employment](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/migration-node.html) in Germany.
>
> **Who can Apply for EU Blue Card in Germany**
>   EU citizens do not need a visa or a residency permit to neither enter nor start working within Germany. The same applies for the citizens of Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway and Switzerland. A valid passport or identity card is sufficient.
>
> Citizens of the following states can enter Germany without a visa but cannot take up employment before applying for the EU Blue Card: Australia, Israel, Japan, Canada, South Korea, New Zealand, the United States of America.
>
> The time allowed to stay in Germany for the citizens of the aforementioned countries is approximately 3 months which is usually not sufficient to find employment therefore the request for an EU Blue Card is obligatory. You may apply during your stay in Germany.
>
> Citizens of the following states may apply for a work and residence permit after entering Germany without a visa: Andorra, Antigua and Barbuda, Argentina, Bahamas, Barbados, Brazil, Brunei, Darussalam, Chile, Costa Rica, El Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras, Macau, Malaysia, Mauritius, Mexico, Monaco ,Nicaragua, Panama, Paraguay, San Marino, Singapore, Saint Kitts and Nevis, Taiwan, Uruguay, the Vatican, Venezuela
>
> Non-EU citizens, on the other hand, must apply for a visa – employment visa, visit, student, or other type of visa coherent with necessity – while still in their home countries. The required documentation for application should be completed in conformity with the rules of the German Embassy in your home country. Once the visa is obtained, it is obligatory to respect the period allowed to stay.
>
> In case you found a job before entering Germany, then you can immediately apply for the EU Blue Card while in your home country by the help of your employer.
>
> Candidates are categorized in the groups: Highly-qualified workers, Researchers, Students, Vocational Trainees, Seasonal Workers, Intra-Corporate Transferees
>
> **How to Apply for Germany EU Blue Card**
>   To apply, more or less, the same criteria are important to be fulfilled by all EU Blue Card applicants:
>
> - A filled application form, by either you or your German employer
> - A recognized university diploma – for unrecognized professions
> - A valid work contract of at least one year in the hosting state
> - For regulated professions – the equivalent certificate or license of profession
> - Proof that your salary exceeds the average in Germany by 1.5 times or 1.2 times for professions in shortage,
> - A written declaration by your employer
> - A valid travel document
> - Not pose any threat to the public policy, security or health of the hosting state
> - Two passport-size personal photos not older than 6 months
> - Proof of application fee payment
>
> In case of no university degree: 5 years of work experience in particular profession are required when applying for the EU Blue Card.
>
> *Note: To prepare and gather the required documentation, such as the recognition of qualification or translation of documents and other similar documents, you will need approximately 4-6 months. Some member states may be quicker although you will need to keep this detail in mind when interested to apply.
>
> Most of the member states require candidates to apply by setting appointments at the appropriate Embassies or Consulates in their home countries; few member states offer online applications.
>
> The application may be filled by you, your employer or law firm.
>   The application fee payment for issuance is around 140€ while 100€ for renewal of the EU Blue Card.
>
> After handing in the application, you may have to wait for a maximum of 3 months/90 days until processing is complete.
>
> You have the right to appeal against the decision of rejection or withdrawal within three weeks of the decision’s arrival – an attorney can also appeal on your behalf.