# How to apply German Employment Visa (Based on Job Offer) for Non-EU National

Tags: working-visas, germany, employment, german-citizens

I am an Indian Citizen and received a job offer from a German Employer to start working as a Software Engineer.They have offered me a permanent job in Germany and shared a signed job offer which i should use for my Visa application.

Based on my little research, I found that to start working in Germany as a Non-EU national, I have to apply for an Employment Visa(Germany) from India and once it is granted then i have to apply for resident permit once i am in Germany.

But i am not sure about below queries:

a) Which type of Visa i need to apply for permanent job offer

b) what exact documentation/checklist i need for this application.

Please help/share links if already available.

Thanks

Comment: Have you asked your prospective employer for advice? I’d expect them to be willing to help, since they’ve offered you a job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply for EU Blue Card after receiving job offer from Germany?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/how-do-i-apply-for-eu-blue-card-after-receiving-job-offer-from-germany)